How can these humans cross the ocean(s) at the first possible chance?
In my worldbuilding project, humans* evolved on a different planet - a bit larger than Earth, a bit warmer. Their rate of advancement is similar to IRL humans, maybe a bit faster.
The planet has two continental masses, separated by oceans of 4500 and 4600 kilometers at the narrowest points. One narrowest point is in the polar regions at the furthest point of the continent to the east from where they evolve, the second one is in the tropics and fairly close to where they've evolved, located West from their point of origin. Humans start at the smaller continent.
By the currently established lore, I need these humans to have a population on the second continent by ~20 000 years ago. On our planet, humans began settling Americas at ~ 23-12 000 years ago, but they had a handy land bridge. I don't have this option here (Ice age that significantly lowers the sea level also is not an option due to the planet being warmer), the best I can do is to make a chain of volcanic islands in the ocean where it would be more convenient (I assume it would be the equatorial option?).

So, how can my people cross it in any way in the allocated timeframe? I don't need a huge migration, just something that would be enough to not die out and start spreading over the continent.
In my setting they partially adapted to live a semi-aquatic lifestyle (meaning - having to deal with swimming frequently, not evolving to depend on water biologically), so I think it would be a good assumption they'll arrive at the various sea-related technologies like boats earlier than IRL humans did.
* Not actually humans, aliens... But for the sake of simplicity let's assume they're humans.

Archaeologists are terrible for underestimating ancient peoples.  For example, we know Melanesians had to cross Wallace's Line to reach Australia, and we know that the descendants of these people reached South America.  But I still see people come up with absurdly convoluted explanations for how they really went to Siberia and back down from North America, leaving no descendants along the way.  Is it really that implausible to think that intelligent human beings built boats?

Your planet can't be that much warmer than Earth since it has ice caps. Earth itself has been warm enough to lack them at various points in its history. Your planet might tend a bit warmer than Earth on average, but it's in basically the same climate range and ice ages would not be unexpected.

Darth - why wouldn't they use rafts, as humans did ?????  you can make a raft out of any old knickknacks.  "an old log" makes a great raft

@ N.Virgo
On one hand, I have a spotty knowledge of the climate, but on the other hand, this planet has a smaller axial angle than Earth (just 5 degrees over our 23 degrees resulting in overall milder seasons) and the general spread of the continents should also prevent ocean currents from pushing hotter water into the polar regions. Maybe the polar ice caps are too big, but I think they still should exist in these conditions, no? It's supposed to have an average temperature of 19°C

@MikeSerfas huh, that is interesting. It seems like at least one paper casts doubts on whether the melanesian connection is really there, but I absolutely don't know the genomics to analyze the merits of those papers. This was cool to read about. I don't know if they're underestimating them as much as being cautious until there's more evidence; a lot of them sort of gesture at "how and when this population reached S.America remains an open question" and I'm sure nobody wants to make that claim unless they have a smoking gun.

@DarthBiomech  "milder seasons" actually means potentially less livable area.  You're avoiding the super cold winters, yes.  But the cost is that you don't get the summers that are just warm enough to actually have a growing season. A lot will depend on specifics of ocean currents and wind patterns to be sure, but you could easily end up substantially reducing the highest latitudes where plants grow decently.

your "chain of islands" idea is perfectly plausible, since we almost had that on Earth. Both Vikings and Native Australians proved you can hop to other continents by way of island stops. Both Atlantic and the Pacific are just a few island shuffles away from having an equatorial chain of islands all within reach by the most primitive raft.

Here is the same map with a more reasonable projection:

(Mollweide equal-area projection of Darth Biomech's World, made with NASA's G.Projector.)
Option 2 is about three quarters of the distance of option 1, and moreover the prevailing winds at 40° northern latitude are likely blowing west to east.
If I may make a suggestion, the lonely mid-ocean island at 10° to 20° southern latitude can be moved north in the middle of the option 2 gap; it would cover about half the distance and would leave two much smaller gaps to be crossed.
Oh, and in the real world, we have recovered boats made by us non-aquatic humans about 10,000 years ago. Since it is quite unlikely that we have found the first boat ever made, the knowledge of how to make boats is probably much older.

The prevailing winds along the option 2 route would naturally push any boat toward the desired continent. A group of ocean hunters could easily be blown way off course and end up on the other continent. You would have to have it happen to enough people in a short time to get a healthy breeding population.

Minor Frame Challenge

separated by oceans of 4500 and 4600 kilometers at the narrowest points.

You are measuring global distances on a square map.  These crossing actually have a distance ratio of about 1.4:1 with Option #1 being much farther.  This is because square projected maps compensate for the curvature of the planet by stretching out stuff the farther you get from the equator; so, if you must pick between these 2 options, Option #2 is in fact significantly shorter.
Option #3: Arctic crossing
Due to complications with your projections, you are in fact missing the shortest possible route.  While it is hard to tell from a square projected map, the distance between The large Northern island on the far side of the polar icecap and the second continent is over 4 times shorter than option 2 and about 6 times shorter than option 1.
If you have a population of nomadic people who survive on a staple of arctic fauna like seals, walruses, fish, etc. then we can consider the coastal regions of your polar ice caps as marginally habitable as soon as clothing and hunting tools are invented which would be somewhere around 100,000-500,000 BCE. This would allow for the possibility of people footing it to the island on the other side of your arctic circle as they pursue these moving coastal food sources.
Furthermore, it's proximity to the arctic means that you only need 1 mini-ice-age to create an ice bridge allowing people to just walk across without needing boats at all.  Given your time scales, you should have at least 1 major volcanic eruption or meteor impact capable of temporarily extending an icebridge here. So you may not even need boats to be invented first... but even if you don't do this, the crossing may be far enough south for trees, and thus the easier discovery of boat based fishing in this region allowing a much easier crossing with smaller more primitive boats.


Boats can be made of bones and animal hides, no need for trees. Groups of hunters would undoubtely use these kind of boats to follow their preys in the arctic area, island hopping in search of new resources. They would most likely also follow birds that would lead them to the next nidification island. In the end, after generations, they may reach the 2nd continent with the knowledge of how to move in that polar sea.

@DuncanDrake Larger ocean going Umiaks, those in the 30-60ft range, used drift wood for the main beam; so, they were not 100% skin and bone, but it is a very good point that arctic people do not need to have a local source of wood to make suitable long range boats.

@Nosajimiki  And, depending on what there is for megafauna, a main beam made of bone might be practical.  Mammoths had femurs about four feet long, which is just a little shorter than a small umiak, and titanosaurs could reach 8 feet long, which is more than long enough.  If you need more flexibility than bone, composites made from horn might work, and the Triceratops horns were about 4 feet long, so that would be a nice, workable length.

@Perkins if you are going ot use titanosaurs don't bother with femurs use ribs which will be longer, curved, and about he same dimensions as heavy ship planks.

@John  Curved doesn't work so well for various parts, but yes, the ribs would also be highly useful.

@Perkins  Titanosaur ribs are not much longer than their femurs. with neither exceeding 3m long.  Either way, you're not going to be able to make the beam of a particularly large boat from bone.  Best case scenario, you'll be able to come up with some manner of lashed cage design, but I don't imagine that being structurally sound enough to endure any sort of rough waters.

@Nosajimiki Bone is often comparable to wood in strength. Details depend on which bones and which species of course. And skin-boats like the umiak, kayak, and curragh can be built out of shorter sections.  An average ocean-going Umiak has a 20ft keelson made of two 10ft sections tennoned together.  Using titanosaur femurs would knock it down to 18 feet, which is still long enough. And three sections would probably work if someone really wanted the extra length. Beam is usually about ten feet, so single femurs would work for the thwarts.

@Perkins A Curragh does not rely on a central beam like a Umiak does; so, that design could work... except it's probably way more complex than any boats that would have existed 20,000 years ago.  Even a Umiak takes a considerable suspension of disbelief as being that old of a design.  Not saying it could not be possible, just that it would represent a very high degree of sophistication considering our understanding of the time period in question.

@Nosajimiki From the papers I found on skin-boat design analysis, we really have no idea how old any of them are.  Between the materials they are made from and the environment in which they are used and stored, they simply don't survive.  We can't even really tell if the design similarities across broad geographical regions are the result of convergence or of shared parentage. To my mind, the question will be if a semi-aquatic race will have greater focus on boat-building due to being in the water constantly, or less due to their natural abilities making them less necessary.

@Nosajimiki it depends a lot on the species of titanosaur, the high shoulder ones have drastically longer ribs, the tall hipped ones have a longer femur. In the more camarasaurus-form ones the are nearly identical.

A confluence of factors

Abundant trees with large tall trunks. The dugout canoe is likely the first type of boat to be "invented" by a civilization.
Ease of oceanic subsistence. If fishing is a highly effective subsistence strategy, then boats become more common and get larger sooner.
Large calm rivers near your civilization's core. The proximity to an easily navigable river will incentivize the want to use the rivers for food and transportation.
Unpredictable storms, good rain, and favorable wind patterns. What you're really counting on is that a number of people who are in a boat (whether fishing, or traveling), then they get caught in a storm or strong wind and blown to a different place. In this case the route is irrelevant. The people don't have a map to know where they're going, they just accidentally go where the wind takes them. Daily rainstorms will ensure sufficient drinking water, if they can fish then they can eat. While not everyone in these circumstances will survive, if this kind of thing is fairly common, eventually they'll just get there by accident (which is really the only way unless you have some way of them seeing the map of your planet).


Huh, interestingly, the planet fits almost all of those. It has tree species that to an extreme can grow up to half a kilometer tall, the oceans are abundant with sealife of all sizes, and rivers are a major presence all across the planet. Not sure about unpredictable storms, but possibly?

The first type of boat is almost certainly the raft.  It's easier to tangle a bunch of tree branches together than it is to carve out a log.

If they are partially adapted to a semi aquatic lifestyle, it might be easier for them to spread across the ocean like the first Polynesian settlers did around 4000 years ago, basically island hopping on boats until some of them reaches the other continent.
Their adaptation can make them less dependent of finding islands along the way, allowing them to endure longer crossing travels.

The Polynesian expansion over the ocean began 4,000 years ago; but the real long distance colonization is very much more recent. The Polynesians reached Samoa about 3,300 years ago, Tahiti about 2,500 years ago, Hawaii about 900 years ago, and New Zealand only about 700 years ago. The Europeans, coming from the other end of the world, arrived in New Zealand only about 400 years after the Polynesians.

@AlexP
I think the key point is that it took them only ~3000 years to expand once they've begun doing it. So now the question is - could they discover the right things to start that expansion much earlier?

The timing of the first peoples to arrive in the Americas may be a lot earlier than was originally thought. https://www.livescience.com/archaeology/the-1st-americans-were-not-who-we-thought-they-were

Rafts
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kon-Tiki_expedition
Back in 1947, five Norwegians and a Swede sailed a raft from South America to Polynesia in an attempt to prove a theory about how the islands were originally populated. The theory is generally considered debunked, but in fact the raft worked! Whether or not it happened, it could have happened. No modern technology needed, all you need is the right kind of logs, some rope, a primitive sail and a few Norwegians people crazy enough to go floating out into the ocean.
P.S. Heyerdahl's book is great too, well worth a read.

Assuming you're thinking about them specifically sailing then the northern route is the easier option. Equatorial waters are notoriously hard to sail around, they're called the doldrums and being becalmed in them was the nightmare of ships' captains right up into and through the age of sail. Earlier vessels simply couldn't cross the equator in the open ocean, they had to coast hop north or south until they could find reliable easterly or westerly wind systems to cross large expanses of water. If on the other hand they can harness up an Avanc or something smaller and more sensible, then they can run the equator quite easily.

Well, sailing is the first thing to come to mind, but honestly, I don't care. Even accidental-log-riding will do if it's feasible.

@DarthBiomech They can make the northern crossing in just about anything with a sail without any additional land being placed for the sake of the journey, the equatorial route is only possible along the line suggested with an alternative force to push/pull the boat(s) along.

An Avanc or, you know, oars...  Oars were included on a lot of ship designs right up until steam engines started replacing them.

@Perkins Happy to be wrong but my understanding was always that oars were for combat, or sometimes short stints when becalmed or island hopping, long-range, and we are talking about thousands of kilometres, travel didn't, couldn't, rely on them.

@Ash Right.  And that's why ships that sailed equatorial waters regularly tended to have oars long after other designs had abandoned them, because while the dead-air pockets around the equator can last a long time, they're often not all that big.  But the key is that you want to be crossing the equatorial waters, not sailing along them just asking to run into another pocket.  You don't use oars for long distances if you can avoid it since it's exhausting work and not particularly fast. But it's better than being stuck in the doldrums for months with your food and water running out.

Aspidochelones.  I think Earth peoples simply used boats, so the only way to make my answer interesting is to propose something better than a boat.  Earth has a number of traditional stories of aspidochelones ("island turtles"), a tortoise which resembles an island.  I'd suggest reworking this tradition, rubbing off a few of the less believable aspects and turning it into a viable ecosystem.
The aspidochelone is an alien organism a few times larger than the Earthly blue whale, perhaps 30 x 10 meters.  That's not a large living area, but these animals are gregarious and not terribly competitive, so typically there is one family hut per 'tortoise', surrounded by gardens and livestock.  The ecological niche of the aspidochelone depends on its ability to deliver an elevated sunlit perch and fresh water (as serum) to the roots of symbiotic plants which grow into its shell.  The plants provide the turtle's very slow metabolism with a steady supply of fructose in exchange, making it a photosynthetic vertebrate.  The aspidochelone also supplies nitrogen, phosphorus, and other nutrients to the plants, and takes additional protein and energy from the environment, by collecting food.  But how can it collect food without moving?  The answer is that the tortoises lay vast rafts of eggs.  The larvae that hatch begin as plankton feeders, feeding for many miles around the pod of aspidochelones.  They return to "pupate" in hollows of the turtle's plastron linked to vestigial cavities derived from its ancestors' digestive systems.  The parent's system feeds the growth of a select few larvae which pass every morphological, behavioral, and genetic screening.  But the ones which fail the test serve as the food; they are resorbed to feed the others and the parent.
The new larvae that eclose and swim out into the world are adept predators and cannibals - any larvae that 'forgot' to submit to the parental cull are no match for them.  They feed on one another for a few weeks until the pickings grow scarce, then go out into the deep ocean to mature.  Decades later, when they are much too large and well-armored to be at risk from one another, they settle into reproductive pods and enjoy their final stage of life as 'island turtles'.
The humans who settle upon these beasts need to accept slow migrations as a part of their lifestyle, because the larvae need to encounter fresh flows of plankton as the aspidochelones swim into the richest currents.  They also need to be careful.  Take too much fruit from a plant, so that it fails to deliver fructose to the turtle, and it will be embargoed from its water supply and die.  Kill too many plants, and the turtle will wake into desperate action and rub its whole back against the 'coastline' of a mate to reseed with better-adapted plants.  Building campfires on the ground is right out.

Given the larva you describe...  so is swimming...

Exodus in an Ark
You could invent some reasons why a "Noah" type of guy had the idea to build a very large ship (or something like a better raft). With space for many people and food.
Staying in the religious trope to explain the inspiration (@PaulSmith: this is not drawing from "supernatural" higher forces to cross the sea at an instant!):
Then they embarked to sea, "giving their life into the hands of (their) god(s)" and ended up at the other continent in the "sacred land".
Can be done without sails, because "their belief carries further than the wind", so only sea currents matter on their journey, if that is needed.
Since the ship is large and human/aliens are numerous the journey can even last long, like an odyssey, until they finally arrive.
It's only a broad idea, you surely can fill in details as you see fit.
Alternatively to an religious trope you can also invent some "mastermind" like Leonardo daVinci or Archimedes combined with the "explorer's mind" of a Phileas Fogg or Cristopher Columbus.

If you are going to rely on the supernatural, you don't need reason.

@PaulSmith: You misunderstood. I don't assume the supernatural to be needed to cross the sea. I just take religious belief as a reason why it could be possible that one (or a few) people had an idea that motivated them to go to sea to cross it. But this idea can also come from something else, that would be subject to the plot. The answer still provides one way of explaining the spreading of "humankind" across continents on that planet using the available resources (e.g. large trees and preparing with lots of food for a long journey).

This is a great idea, doesn't matter if what they beleive is true or not it's a motivation.

If you have no idea how boats work, there is NO WAY you are just building a big ship and cross an ocean on the first try. You will probably sink or capsize and drown with the coast you started from still in sight.
Boats that can cross oceans with primitive technology are possible, but a long term solid culture of seafaring is necessary to figure out how to best build and handle them first. Than all is needs is some people bold enough and with some luck to try.

@LazyLizard: I doubt the "NO WAY" part, but I agree with you on your last sentence. I also did not imply "[having] no idea how boats work" in this scenario.

@Antares The OP implied that part by setting it 20 kYA. And by having the crossing be a problem in the first place. If you can build a giant boat, you can also build a normal boat and cross the ocean in that. A raft or canoe made by stone-age people might get (really) lucky and get carried to the right shore without running into bad weather first.  A large ship made by stone-age people collapses under its own weight (or takes on huge amounts of water immediately; the failure mode will depend on the type of ship, but bigger is harder) while it's still in dock^h^h^h^h shallow waters.

@Ray: I think you look at it too narrow-scoped in terms of "everything has to happen as in our history" (maybe read the paragraphs below the picture in the question again). The problem at hand is "how" not so much "why not". What is and what is not "happening" is to decide by the OP.

@Antares I don't think the problem is with Ray's scope. The Titanic is an example of what happens when you think you can build a big boat. Noah's ark is a fanciful story, it is not a practical solution to a problem so unless you want the story to have a god, alien or the wizard of Oz dictate construction instructions, building an ark is not a believable option.

@PaulSmith Thanks for trying to be helpful, but it is futile. As I said above, what is believable or what is happening or is possible is solely a thing decided by the OP. Of course there are people who have different opinions on things. There are things to agree and disagree. Both is fine. Discussing it just leads nowhere. I won't react to different opinions on the answer I gave anymore, because that is not the topic here. I should flag those comments as "unhelpful" maybe.

In a similar vein as others .  Maybe with some of your trees being half a kilometer (huge) then a tsunami and/or landslide deposited both enormous floating trees and fauna in a watery environment but some group of mostly unrelated survivors from a small community were dumped in also and they were able to use this huge object(s) to stay on while floating on a gulf stream type ocean current to a new continent. Very little tech needed. Animals have done this countless times. Maybe the tree has something that helps them survive, maybe they were fisherman types anyway before this and that helped them survive etc etc etc.

For a more creative solution, try a floating island lifeform that the sentients use (either passively or actively). Imagine a tree that floats across the ocean, its root matter creating a wide raft-like form. I'm thinking mangrove-like trees but with many more roots. This would make a floating ecosystem both topside, within the roots and branches, and below, within the water under the safety of the root mass.
All sorts of possibilities, opportunities, tensions and dangers are inherent in here for stories. For example:

sentients could obtain water and food from a variety of animals and fruits from this ecosystem
larger (higher food-chain) water or flying creatures could pose a constant threat, or even a small creature that grows on the island into a large aggressive one
the available food/water may slowly run out as the journey continues, forcing the sentients to adapt
if the island had some locomotive element, no matter how small, to move where it wants to go, the sentient could potentially harness that movement
if the island was, for example, in its last stage of a lifecycle, it might be suffering slow degradation as it floats across the ocean (or nears the opposing continent), eventually breaking up into thousands of seed pods (providing an incentive to reach the land rather than remain on the island). The sentients might be forced to try ways of keeping it together
the sentients may have worked out a way to prolong this phase of the island creature by, for example, feeding it fish-equivalents, or other sentients
the mating phase of the island creatures may be interesting for the sentients to negotiate. For example, if it involved the meeting of two trees, then this might be dangerous for the sentients. Or if it involved some bird or bat-like creature pollinating flowers, this might be a new food opportunity for the sentients
the sap may be used in some way (additional water/food, intoxicant, poison for spear tips)
storms may pose a huge survival crisis, especially with roots moving against each other, with crushing and trapping potential


The 'shortest' distance is a meaningless concept in a society without modern navigation aids. The Irish, Vikings, and many, many other groups of people have sailed over the horizon. Some survived, some didn't. Of those that survived, some thrived, most died out. The minimum requirements that I can think of are a coastal population with a fish based diet and a trade based economy. Fishing means they wont starve on their journey, trade gives them a reason to travel to explore new opportunities.
To actually settle somewhere over the horizon and create a viable multi-generational community requires quite a sizeable minimum population, which means either multiple vessels or the ability to make return and repeat journeys. This implies explorers who were able to go somewhere and come back again and settlers who are willing to follow the paths the explorers have found.

Hardly needs modern navigation tools.  An sextant, a compass, and a book of lunar distance tables to go with your charts will do.  So that's 1759.  The major impediment to taking the shortest route was the necessity of following the patterns of favorable winds more than an inability to know where things were.

The OP stipulated the travellers were the human equivalent of 20,000 years ago, not 300 years ago. They had no sextants or charts. They didn't, and couldn't know what the shortest distance to another continent was because they couldn't know there was another continent.

Sextant and charts are necessary for precision. But people have been sailing beyond the horizon, successfully, just with the patterns in the stars, for a very, very long time.  The point was more that if your craft is powered by the wind, then shortest time is very much not the same as shortest distance, regardless of how advanced your navigation aids may be.

Easy. Either the ocean salinity is lower than the Earth's, or your aliens have better kidneys and they are capable of drinking seawater indefinitely (or, being aliens, they even might not have kidneys). Quite likely in fact, being semiaquatic.
Or more likely, a combination of both factors.
And if they can subsist on fishing, all it takes is one fishing family being blown by a storm and they could survive many months on the open ocean, finally drifting to the other continent. It happened all the time on Earth since the invention of the boat, but people usually perished, water being THE major problem.

In point of fact, humans not being able to survive on seawater is something of an oddity.  A very large portion of other mammals can.  Primates are one of the few categories which can't reabsorb water against a salt gradient from the bladder.  And there are quite a few anecdotes over the centuries suggesting that at least some bloodlines of humans possibly can under the right circumstances.
